# Google Civic API missing state representatives

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm working on a project to map out the legislators who represent students. We're looking in Virginia, and we've run into a few issues with normal addresses. Here's an example:

112 Howard St, Floyd, VA, 24091 returns data going all the way down to the county level, but doesn't include state representatives. Google's even normalizing the address (including the "SE" at the end of "112 Howard St") - so I know that it's looking in the right location.

I've double-checked the data against the official records on the Virginia Assembly website (https://whosmy.virginiageneralassembly.gov/) and this address should (currently) list L. Nick Rush as state delegate and David R. Suetterlein as state senator - and the boundaries (on the Virginia General Assembly site above) for their districts put this address right in the middle.

I'm at a loss here - does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You might want to post to the support channel specifically for that API: https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/ci_forum.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I somehow missed that in all my digging.